# Exclude some design unit from code coverage on Questasim

Tags: modelsim, uvm, questasim

I run a code coverage on questasim and I got ucdb file as output. But I need to exclude code coverages of some modules that connect to the top module.I don't need some of modules to be covered which this I can improve coverage report.

How can I do it without run simulation again?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used a command as shown below.

```
coverage exclude -du <design_unit>
```

or

```
coverage exclude -srcfile <design_file>
```

Reference: [QuestaSim User Manual](https://www.academia.edu/11505187/Questa_sim_user_manual)